# http request in javascript pdf api

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm trying to do a get request with the javascript api to adobe reader. I'm using the Net.http object with the following code:

```
get =  app.trustedFunction (function(cURL)
{
    app.beginPriv();
    var params =
     {
        cVerb: "GET",
        cURL: "HTTP://ip_addr/checker/comments/1",
        oHandler:
        {
            response: function(msg, uri, e)
                {
                    if(e != undefined && e.error != 405) {
                        app.alert("Failed to get: "+ e);
                    } else app.alert("connected");
                }
              }
        };
        Net.HTTP.request(params);
    app.endPriv();
 });
```

When I call the function in my code, the first time the program opens its working fine and can connect.

The problem is that when I call the function again using a submenu like this:

```
  app.addMenuItem ({cName: "connect", cParent: "Edit", cExec: "get()"});
```

I get an error, I also tried adding this PDF file to my privileged locations because I think it's a security related issue

Any idea?

Comment: "I get an error" — How about sharing the error message with us?

Comment: the pdf javascript debugger doesnt really give out useful error massages.
when i try to run the function from the menu the dubugger open up with an arrow pointing to the row "Net.HTTP.request(params)
and in the console i get: "Exception in line 44 of function anonymous, script Folder-Level:App:button.js"